# Token based authentication in Flask

Tags: python

I am trying to create token for logged in user for a particular duration and using g.user to keep track of current user.

`generate_auth_token` and `verify_auth_token` belong to class User.

However I keep getting this error:

> g.user.generate_auth_token(600)                                                                          'dict' object has no attribute 'generate_auth_token'

```
def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=600):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=expiration)
    return s.dumps({'id': self.id})

@staticmethod
def verify_auth_token(token):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        data = s.loads(token)
    except SignatureExpired:
        return None  # valid token, but expired
    except BadSignature:
        return None  # invalid token
    user = users.find_one({'username': userdata['username']})['_id']
    return user

@auth.login_required
def get_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token(600)
    return json.dumps({'token': token.decode('ascii'), 'duration': 600})

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    user = User.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    if not user:
        user = users.find_one({'username': username_or_token})
        if not user or not pwd_context.verify(password, user['password']):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True
```

What is the mistake I made and what's the best way to do token authentication in flask for pymongo?

Comment: `g.user` is a *dictionary*, not a `User` instance. This is probably what `users.find_one()` returns.

Comment: What would you think would be the best way to get user instance. I am referencing this blog to build token based authentication: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask#commentform

Comment: The technique in the blog is solid and great. But your *implementation* is lacking here. I don't know how `pymongo` works here, but clearly it is not returning an instance of the `User` class. Perhaps there are techniques to turn the Mongo results into a Python class instance (like SQLAlchemy does in the tutorial you found), but I haven't worked with Mongo myself so I can't answer that part.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Object-Document-Mapper for your *User* class.

Try this

- Use MongoEngine as your ODM. (There are other options like MongoFrames)

Here is a working example using MongoEngine as the ODM https://github.com/timosville/rest_auth_mongodb

Answer (score 0):

define `generate_auth_token` method inside the `User` class